# Print a void function in C language

Tags: c, function, return-value, void

I'd like to print the result of shell sorting an array with 1000 elements. The function is of type `void`, so I want to know how to retrieve the value "returned" from the function (not really returned, actually the result). That's my code until now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
void shellsort(int v[], int n)
{
    int gap, i, j, temp;
    for (gap = n / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2)
        for (i = gap; i < n; i++)
            for (j = i - gap; j >= 0 && v[j] > v[j + gap]; j -= gap)
                temp = v[j];
    v[j] = v[j + gap];
    v[j + gap] = temp;


}
int main()
{

    int i;
    int my_array[1000];

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        my_array[i] = rand();
    }

    shellsort(my_array, 1000);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, "print a void function"? void functions have no return value, therefore they can't return anything to print.

Comment: Heck, what do you even mean by "print a function"?

Comment: You surely don't want to print the function itself.  Since it doesn't return anything, you cannot want to print its return value, either.  I guess you want to print the contents of the array being sorted, either before the sort, after, or both.  So do that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You just want to print out the sorted elements? Why not just `for (i=0; i<1000; i++) { printf("%d\n", my_array[i]); }`, similar to how you populated the elements?

Comment: I think they meant that they want to print the return value, but there is no return value, and this confuses them.

Comment: Apart from the question about "printing a function": There is a `{ ... }`-block missing around the body of the innermost loop.

Comment: @Kusalananda  it is syntactically correct, if poor practice.

Comment: @WeatherVane Whether it is poor practice is dependent on your current coding standard/enforced style.

Comment: @WeatherVane Without the block, the algorithm is wrong, no? All three statements belongs in it.  It's a standard swap thing.

Comment: OP wants "to print the 1000 elements in the array sorted using Shell Sort", which just means he wants to print the sorted array.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry yes, you are right. I was fooled by the bad indentation.

Comment: Actually, for readability, braces should be used for all loops.

Answer (score 2):

In C, arrays pass "as reference" (as a pointer, for more advanced C programmers) to functions. That means that any change the function makes to an array affects the array in the caller function.
That means, that `my_array` (after calling the function) now holds the **sorted array** (because the function modified it).
So, instead of a return value, you can just print `my_array`, like that:

```
int main()
{

    int i;
    int my_array[1000];

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        my_array[i] = rand();
    }

    shellsort(my_array, 1000);

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note: in **C** there is no such thing as _"passing by reference"_. In **C** an array is passed as a _pointer to its first element_. The pointer is passed _by value_, but the array is not copied, which allows the called function to modify its contents.

Comment: A pointer is **not** a reference! And you don't pass an array by pointer (at least not as array), but a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Of course, of course. But saying "passing by reference" is much clearer to a beginner (assuming that he hasn't yet learnt pointers and more complicated subjects)

Comment: Eh. Using the wrong terminology to hold beginners' hands doesn't help them out in the long run imo.

Answer (score 0):

Change the innnermost forloop to

```
for (j = i - gap; j >= 0 && v[j] > v[j + gap]; j -= gap)
   {  
    /* You need {} for a block of statements
     * if you miss the {}, the forloop will have only the next immediate
     * statement under its jurisdiction
     */
    temp = v[j];
    v[j] = v[j + gap];
    v[j + gap] = temp;
   }
```

A function of type void  won't return anything. However, since you get the sorted array back in the `main`.

So you can print the array using a simple `for-loop` like

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", my_array[i]);
    }
```